# Can't view contact groups page: "DataTables warning"

Tags: groups

We can't view the main groups page -- a popup error appears and no groups are shown. The error is:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - 
Invalid JSON response. For more information about 
this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, turning on logging (**civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1**) and looking in the CiviCRM log reveals a fatal error related to mapping and geocoding:

> Proximity searching requires you to set a valid geocoding provider

Somebody had tried to set up a proximity group based on zip codes, but the mapping and geocoding settings had not been configured. Configuring the geocoding (**civicrm/admin/setting/mapping?reset=1**) to use Google as the provider fixed the issue.